# Comparing Selected Date Range With Current & Previous Month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to provide the user to option to select a range of date in current month and results should be comparison of same date range for current & previous month.
Eg. selected date 1-12-2022 to 15-12-2022
Result:

```
Count X 1-11-2022 to 15-11-2022
Count X 1-12-200 to 15-12-2022
```

Can this be achieved through date_part function?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: So, which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm working on Postgres.

Comment: Could you share a sample of your input table and the expected output, as a tabular text. It seems you need to use conditional aggregation or filtered count function, maybe?

Comment: What result do you want when the user selects a date range in the current month which contains a day(s) of month that does not exist in the prior month. Example: What is the result when user select date range `2022-03-15` - `2022-03-31`?  The days 29, 20, 31 do not exist in the prior month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a column with type `date` named `ts` in your table:

```
SELECT
    count(*) FILTER ( WHERE ts BETWEEN cast(:lower AS DATE) - INTERVAL '1 month' AND cast(:upper AS DATE) - INTERVAL '1 month') previous,
    count(*) FILTER ( WHERE ts BETWEEN cast(:lower AS DATE) AND cast(:upper AS DATE) ) selected,
    count(*) FILTER ( WHERE ts BETWEEN cast(:lower AS DATE) + INTERVAL '1 month' AND cast(:upper AS DATE) + INTERVAL '1 month' ) next
FROM your_table;
```

You just need to provide the `lower` and `upper` bound values as dates (e.g. '01-12-2022'.
This will give you 3 columns -- `previous`, `selected` and `next` -- with the corresponding row-counts.
BTW: the upper bound is exclusive.